# Edit old answer and obsolete methods

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits, obsolete-information

At Stack Overflow I tried to edit [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3553731/1083946) because the suggested methods are now obsolete. So I added a warning and the related references.

The [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/594377) has been rejected with the following motivation: "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.".

I think that I've tried to update a valid answer, without editing the original content and warning the reader about an obsolete method.

Why has the edit been rejected?

Comment: A link to the suggested edit would help.

Comment: This is the edit you're talking about? http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/594377

Comment: If you are lucky and the answerer is online and willing to incorporate the information, you might get approved for such edit. In general, it is quite hard for such edit to get approved, unless you get reviewers who are knowledgeable on the subject and agree with you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given [the particular edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/594377), it might be merely seen as a comment on the answer, rather than an additional answer in itself. I might have done the same. It is a tricky situation.

Yes, it is an update, and yes, this is a collaboratively edited Q&A. But in practice I find that anything which goes beyond a minor correction of content (like your entire addition which somewhat invalidates the answer) is likely to be rejected.

The easiest thing to do would be to leave an answer of your own with the currently correct approach. You could then leave a comment on the original answer stating that, while originally the correct answer, the situation has changed somewhat as detailed in your answer.

Comment: In fact I did as you suggested, changing the edit into a comment. Still it is not clear why the edit has been rejected as the "[Edit question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit)" page states: "_When should I edit posts? [...] to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages_".

Comment: @ADC Yes, that is what it says. And in a perfect world that would be what applies. In practice it unfortunately doesn't always. Many feel that such edits are too substantial. Especially if they read (though I'm hugely exaggerating here) "What you read above is wrong". Your intentions are good, the content is probably valuable, but many don't feel comfortable accepting such edits. Neither would I in most cases. So I can only recommend a practical alternative.

Comment: IMHO collaborative Q&A is good as far as people are encouraged in collaborating. A clear set of rules is fondamental in guiding people. If a rule is stated it should be applied  both by editors and by reviewers. If it is not, well then the rule should be changed or removed.